# How to use R DBI to create a view?

Tags: r, r-dbi, rjdbc

I'm trying to use R's DBI library to create a view on an Athena database, connected via JDBC.  The `dbSentStatement` command, which is supposed to submit and execute arbitrary SQL without returning a result, throws an error when no result set is returned:

```
DBI::dbSendStatement(athena_con, my_query)
Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set",  : 
  Unable to retrieve JDBC result set
  JDBC ERROR: [Simba][JDBC](11300) A ResultSet was expected but not generated from query <query repeated here>
```

In addition, the view is not created.

I've tried other DBI commands that seemed promising (`dbExecute`, `dbGetQuery`, `dbSentQuery`), but they all throw the same error. (Actually, I expect them all to - `dbSendStatement` is the one that, from the manual, should work.)

Is there some other way to create a view using `DBI`, `dbplyr`, etc.? Or am I doing this right and its a limitation of `RJDBC` or the driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RJDBC pre-dates the more recent DBI specification and uses a different function to access this functionality: `RJDBC::dbSendUpdate(con, query)` .

DBI's `dbSendStatement()` doesn't work here yet. For best compatibility, RJDBC could implement this method and forward it to its `dbSendUpdate()` .